# CSS Поочередная группировка элементов

Tags: css, css3

Есть вот такой вот html

```css
.sv_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.sv_head__list {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="sv_wrapper">
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test1</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test2</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body" hidden>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test3</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body" hidden>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test4</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body" hidden>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Подскажите, какие CSS свойства задать, что б визуально слева были только кнопки, а с права списки. Что б кнопка не растягивалась на величину контента отвечающего за неё списка. 'html' менять нельзя.
То есть в итоге необходимо вот такое отображение. ->

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Пример 1

```css
:root {
  --offset-head: 10px;
}

.sv_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.sv_head__list {
  position: absolute; top: var(--offset-head); left: 0;
  width: 300px;
}

.sv_head__list:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: calc(var(--offset-head) * 4);
}

.sv_head__list:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: calc(var(--offset-head) * 7);
}

.sv_head__list:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: calc(var(--offset-head) * 10);
}

.sv_body {
  padding-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sv_wrapper">
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test1</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test2</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body" hidden>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test3</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body" hidden>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test4</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body" hidden>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Пример 2

```css
.sv_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.sv_head__list {
  position: relative;
}

.sv_body {
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="sv_wrapper">
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test1</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test2</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body" hidden>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test3</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body" hidden>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sv_head__list"><button>test4</button></div>
  <ul class="sv_body" hidden>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но немного не подходит под мою задачу. Контент генерируеться с сервера и непонятно количество кнопок и списков. Так что первый вариант - с абсолютным позиционированием не подходит. А второй, как-то перестает работать когда в списке большое количество элементов. https://jsfiddle.net/r9vL8zjt/

Comment: @BlackStar1991 - вариант с абсолютным позиционированием 2 https://jsfiddle.net/3uon9rq0/1/

Comment: Спасибо, а может всё таки есть решение на `grid` или `flex-box` ? (без привлечения JS) Вроде ж простая композиция?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Еще такой вариант, но также с js https://jsfiddle.net/0fqd8Lsn/